# Which is correct when using the word staff?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

Which sentence is correct? Call center staff receive the information, or call center staff receives the information? I would consider the use of the word Staff as plural in this usage case.

Comment: This may be a a Br v Am thing: many staffs in the US are treated as a singular collective, while our cousins in the Britisphere may celebrate their diversity, so to speak, in the plural.

Comment: It depends on whether your instance of "staff" refers to one staff member or multiple. (1 - as a bullet point) Call centre staff receives the information and relays it to his/her manager. (2) Call centre staff receive the information about their rosters every Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

If the collective noun (staff) is acting as a single unit, use the singular form:

> "The Call center staff receives the information"

If the collective noun is meant to highlight the actions of discrete individuals who are all doing different things, use the plural form:

> "Call center staff receive the information"

I was not sure about this until I read the explanation from this [website](https://www.agriculture.purdue.edu/agcomm/ontarget/0712/Grammer_traps.htm)